# Java regex skipping over matches

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use Java regular expressions to do something I could have sworn I have done many times over, but it seems I have a problem.

Basically, I am using ".*" to skip over everything I don't need until I find something I need.

It is easier for me to explain in code than in writing:

```
String str = "class=\"c\" div=34234542234234</span>correct<?> blah=12354234234 </span>wrong<";      
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("class=\"c\".*</span>([^<]*)");     
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str);       
boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
    found = true;
    System.out.println ("Found match: " + matcher.group(1));            
}       
if (!found)
    System.out.println("No matches found");
```

Now I want my regex to find the "correct", but instead it skips over to the last match and finds "wrong".

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `.*` is greedy and it will try to consume as many characters as possible. I am not sure, but try to use `.*?`, which is reluctant.

Comment: .*? will do what you want, but [parsing HTML with regular expressions is considered harmful.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the [*reluctant qualifier*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) after `*` - it should be `.*?` instead.